# Android Studio: Generated Release APK not working

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Im trying to install an app that i ensure that is working (installation via play button on Android Studio works perfectly fine) however I got an error if I try to install via Play Store or straight via an APK file: **"App not installed"**. This error happened on a Xiaomi Redmi note 5 and not 7 (one of them never had this app installed before).
This happens when I try to install directly through the generated APK release using Android Studio.

Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK -> APK -> Insert my passwords -> Select Release and check both checkboxes (V1 and V2), I've tried only V1 and only V2 and none of them worked...

Now I've tried to go to Build -> Build bundle/APK -> Build APK and it worked to install using the debug file. However I cant upload this file to **Play Store**.
So the problem is on a **RELEASE** version of the APK file. How can I fix it so I can upload it to **Play Store**?

PS: After tried this debug file on a third device, it didn't work either. 
**All 3 devices worked** if I install directly from **Android Studio play button** though.

Here is my build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.appdidier.hospitalar"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    ////    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    //    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
        implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1'
        implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"
        implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    //    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    }
```

Comment: What build variants are you generating to publish in the play store? you should also check if you have problems with the proguard

Comment: Hi @JuanE.LondoñoT. and thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "variants"? If you mean both check boxes (Jar Signature and Full APK Signature) I've explained on the question, tried with all combinations already. Now regard to proguard, I had no issues with it.

Comment: look in the following [link](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example) you can see a little more about the build variants, in case it has different variants of your app. App not installed, I got that error when I tried to install a release apk that was not signed or had a debug version previously installed and when I tried to install the release version it generated the error.

Comment: thanks again @JuanE.LondoñoT.but i didnt even use variants before.. thats not my first app, however this is the first time that this error appears. All other apps were able to be published correctly. I guess something had changed on this new Android Studio version which causes this generated APK to not work

Answer (score 0):

Ive ended up solving my problem by removing this line of code on the manifest file:

```
android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

So sad that Google dont have a report to debug this problem... I had a lot of trouble to find it.
Too hard to find a solution when the problem is just: "App not installed"